# How to reference a cell as table range when using vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have vlookups to pull specific data from a workbook and paste into a new workbook in the desired layout. The layout of the first workbook never changes however the name will change when i want to run this on a different file.

My current formula is `=VLOOKUP(A3,[Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1!$B$3:$XFD$7,2,FALSE)`

I would really like it to reference `A1` instead of `Workbook1` so I could then just update the file name in A1 every time I want to analyse a different file. I should mention the Sheet name won't ever change.

I know you have to use `INDIRECT` but im unsure how it works. I did try `=VLOOKUP(A3,INDIRECT(A1),$B$3:$XFD$7,2,FALSE)` but then i'd too many arguments and when i removed the `$B$3:$XFD$7` i lost the range i was searching in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With INDIRECT you must create the whole string that denotes the range reference:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,INDIRECT("'[" & A1 & "]Sheet1'!$B$3:$XFD$7"),2,FALSE)
```

One more note, that INDIRECT requires that the workbook be open to function, or will return an error.

Comment: Could I also be a pain and ask how to reference a cell on a sheet for my table array? for example `[" & Sheet2!A1 & "]`

Comment: @KyleMoffett just like that.

Comment: Apologies missed the capital 'S' when typing into my formula. Appreciate your help!